# ¿Cómo leer con Scanner un Char o un LocalDate?

Tags: java

Creo el Scanner y para los String no tengo problema, pero para los LocalDate no sé cómo hacerlo. Para leer un `int` existe el método `nextInt()`, para un `String` `nextLine()` pero ¿para un `LocalDate`? y ¿para un `Char`?

Os copio lo que llevo escrito.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File miFichero = new File("PilaDePartes.dat");
    Empresa e = null;
    if (!miFichero.exists()) {
        e = new Empresa();
    } else {
        e = deserializa();
    }
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion; // Guardaremos la opcion del usuario

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("1. Anadir un nuevo parte de trabajo");
        System.out.println("2. Buscar carta por su nombre");
        System.out.println("3. Eliminar una carta");
        System.out.println("4. Listar  todas las cartas");
        System.out.println("5. Listar  todas las cartas nuevas");
        System.out.println("6. Listar  todas las cartas segunda mano");
        System.out.println("7. Buscar la carta mas cara");
        System.out.println("8. Buscar la carta mas barata");
        System.out.println("9. Buscar la carta mas antigua");
        System.out.println("10. Salir");
        System.out.println("*********************************************");
        System.out.println("Elija una de las opciones");

        opcion = Integer.parseInt(entrada.nextLine());

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                String aux = "";
                LocalDate aux1 = null;
                String aux2 = "";
                char aux3 = ' ';
                LocalDate aux4 = null;
                double aux5 = 0;
                String aux6 = "";
                ParteDeTrabajo p = new ParteDeTrabajo();
                Material m = new Material();

               System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del cliente: ");
                aux = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca la fecha del parte: ");
                aux1 = entrada.next
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del trabajador: ");
                aux2 = entrada.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Introduzca el estado de la reparacion:");
                aux3 = entrada. ;




                break;
            case 10:
                salir = true;
                serializa(e);
                entrada.close();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Solo numeros entre 1 y 10");

        }
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para leer un Char tienes que especificar que posición del string de entrada quieres. Se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
// Si quieres coger el primer carácter usa índice 0
char aux = entrada.next().charAt(0);
```

Para leer un LocalDate tienes que asegurarte que la entrada tiene el siguiente formato: `2016-08-16` para poder usar:

```
String dateString = entrada.next();
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
```

Si necesitas otro formato tienes que usar un `DateTimeFormatter` y especificarle que formato de fecha quieres :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy");

String dateString = entrada.next();

//convert String to LocalDate
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

Puedes leer en [la documentación de la clase DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) para ver todos los formatos que acepta.

Comment: vale pero cuando yo esa variable se la asigne a uno de lo setter de la clase como lo monto porque el atributo de la clase es localDate

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta para usar un LocalDate, lo que hay que hacer es lo mismo, lo único que cambia con las clases a utilizar.